# How to pass URL parameters to a CGI in IIS?

Tags: iis, iis-8

I'm pretty new to the IIS game. I have an exe file which is being executed once I do http://localhost/cgi/script.exe. But how do I send parameters to the cgi script from the URL parameters? I am thinking about both http://localhost/cgi/script.exe/param1 and http://localhost/cgi/script.exe?query=howdy

Can anyone help? Google hasn't been too helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Use in script session variable QUERY_STRING in PROCESS namespace, like this:

```
Set wshShell = CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
Set wshUserEnv = wshShell.Environment("PROCESS")
WScript.Echo "Your parameters string is: " & wshUserEnv("QUERY_STRING")
```